# Change object attribute following transition D3

Tags: javascript, attributes, transition, d3.js

I want to give an object an attribute once a transition is finished.  I'm simply updating an images position as follows:

```
tmp.transition().duration(1000)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {return 'translate(' + 
                    coordinates[d].x +',' + 
                    coordinates[d].y + ')'})
```

Once it finishes, I want to give the object tmp an attribute "moved" with the value "no".  I tried:

```
tmp.transition().duration(1000)
     .attr("transform", function(d) {return 'translate(' + 
            coordinates[d].x +',' + 
            coordinates[d].y + ')'}).end('moved', 'no')
```

But without success.  Any tips?  Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each), you can use `.each`:

```
tmp.transition().duration(1000)
 .attr("transform", function(d) {return 'translate(' + 
        coordinates[d].x +',' + 
        coordinates[d].y + ')'}
 ).each('end', function() {
     d3.select(this).attr('moved', 'no');
     // or maybe also this.setAttribute('moved', 'no');
 });
```

Comment: and `each` with "start" for the opposite. this is very handy, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tell javascript to wait for a period of time and run code after using window.setTimeout. You simply have to sync both events up by using the same number of milliseconds.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    //Your fake "callback" code here
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to @user1066286 (and because I cannot post comments): you shouldn't use setTimout() here! Appart from it being bad practice, you cannot guarantee that the transition will actually be completed when the timeout stops.

From the d3 Transition docs:

> Transitions have a four-phase life cycle:
>
> The transition is scheduled.
>   The transition starts.
>   The transition runs.
>   The transition ends.

Each of these four phazes are processed asynchronously, so there's no way to know how long the transition *actually* takes. It maight be a little slower then the user-defined duration, it might be a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

@Felix Klings answer appears to be deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692220/14095529 (block below is quote from that answer).

```
// d3 v5
d3.select("#myid").transition().style("opacity","0").on("end", myCallback);

// old way
d3.select("#myid").transition().style("opacity","0").each("end", myCallback);
```