# Transition function chaining after all transitions are complete

Tags: javascript, d3.js

IU am unrolling a circle into a line, and The way I am doing it (open for other functions as well) is by looping over each state and calling `.transition()…` as so:

```
function all() {
   for(i=0; i<numberOfPoints; i++){
        circle.data([circleStates[i]])
            .transition()
            .delay(dur*i)
            .duration(dur)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr('d', pathFunction)
            .each('end', firstAFterUnroll()); //is this the correct function?
    }
}
```

A 'state' as mentioned above is a path that is part circle, and part line, to give the impression that the line is unrolling.

The `firstAfterUnroll()` is getting called after each iteration, not at the end, which does make sense, I just am unsure of how to adjust the chaining of the ease.  The `firstAfterUnroll()` should get called once after the line unrolls (ie after the for loop finishes executing).

I also tried just calling it outside of the loop, but it gets executed before the loop finishes.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/6sYAY/)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. What exactly do you want to do differently to how it is working in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, didnt spell that out.  The `firstAfterUnroll()` should get called once after the line unrolls (ie after the for loop finishes executing).  I will be chaining another function (`secondAfterUnroll()`) after the `firstAfterUnroll()` as well, so it will be helpful to understand how I should structure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need to call this function only once and that you know exactly when the transition finishes, you can call it after that time using `setTimeout`. Chaining transitions is meant for exactly that and not really to call a single function once.

To call any further functions after that, simply call them from the first function. I've modified your jsfiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6sYAY/17/) with this solution.

Alternatively, you could do something like in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024447/d3-js-transition-end-event) to make sure that the function is only called once.

Comment: OK, so I saw the underscore example in my searching, but the timing was still off.   Could/Should I restructure the animation to chain between each state, so that I could chain the additional functions or is setting the timeout an OK approach?  (the number of points is dynamic)  I think that I will know the fixed time between the different major transitions, so I think that I can rely on static definitions using `setTimeout` as you suggested, but I am also trying to learn correct structure and taking advantage of d3 as much as possible the "correct" way.  Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: Also, do you have a donations page or wish list?   You have helped me sooo much on this site, and I would like to say thank you.  You are a positive influence on my programming in general and especially with my experience on this site, as I have had a rough time 'learning' how to ask questions on this site, given that I've only been really programming for about 9 months.  My [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234721/chris-frisina)

Comment: Chaining transitions and setting the duration is really functionally equivalent. As you are relying on explicitly setting the data, chaining transitions would require a bit of refactoring so that the data would be available with each element. You might call it more D3 though. Also thank you very much for the praise -- I don't really have a wish list or something like that and I'm quite happy to provide help for free here. It's great to hear that it's appreciated though :)

Comment: If you ever decide to get a wish list, let me know:)