# Transition.each("end") never called

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to listen end of the transition event on each of my circles:

```
            var n=0;
            //drawing the plot
            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()                
            .append("circle")                               
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){return xScale(max-createDate(dataset[dataset.length-1-i]["Time"]));})
            .attr("cy", -100)
            .attr("r", 5)                
            .attr("fill", function(d){return d["Doping"]?"#ff1d25":"#009267";})
            .each(function() { n++; console.log(n)})
            .transition()                                
            .delay(function(d,i){return i*50})                
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(d["Place"]);})
            .each('end', function() {                   
                   n--;
                   if (!n) {
                       console.log("end")
                   }
               })
```

But "end" is never printed! What am I doing wrong? 
The full code is [here](http://codepen.io/pbweb/pen/QKmGmP)

Comment: did you see the error in your browsers developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX no error messages =/

Comment: then you are not using your browsers developer tools console ... firefox says `TypeError: t.call is not a function` - the problem is, that your last .each is invalid

Comment: thank you... I can't figure out what s wrong - all the data entries are in the same format ...  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json

Comment: it should be `.on('end',  ...` instead of `.each('end', ...`

Comment: the code is from here (payne8) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024447/d3-js-transition-end-event  Are you familiar with d3? Why this code doesn't work for me and works for them?(

Comment: @JaromandaX - your comment is a valid solution! Thank you

Comment: I'm amazed at that other question - perhaps `.each` worked differently 4 years ago! just checked and there was some change - https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#transitions-d3-transition