# removing parent after child transition ends in D3.js

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

using D3.js, I would like to perform transition (animation) on child element and when at the end of the transition, remove the parent element.

1. how to make sure the child transition ended?
2. how to remove the parent element? in jQuery syntax it would be $(this).parent().remove();

   li.enter()
   .append('li')
     .append('i')
       .text(function (d) { return d; });

   li.exit()
       .selectAll('i')
       .transition()
       .style('opacity', 0)
       .remove(); // remove parent here...

demo:
http://jsbin.com/elaxom/1/edit

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. how to make sure the child transition ended?

I learn here: [Invoke a callback at the end of a transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692100/invoke-a-callback-at-the-end-of-a-transition)
that I can use transition.each([type],listener) like this:
d3.selectAll('i').transition().each('end', function () { ... });
to triggr callback on each of the elements transition 'end' event.

> 2. how to remove the parent element? in jQuery it would be $(this).parent().remove();

this syntax works for me:

d3.select(this.parentNode).transition().style('opacity', 0).remove();

and this is the final demo:
http://jsbin.com/elaxom/4/edit