# Show text only after transition is complete d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am showing data in rectangle on click of circle,

I have put transition on rectangle, Issue is text comes first , what I want is text should come only when transition is complete.

```
    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)

        d3.json("data.json", function (json) {
            /* Define the data for the circles */
            var elem = svg.selectAll("g myCircleText")
            .data(json.nodes)

            /*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */
            var elemEnter = elem.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ",80)" })

            /*Create the circle for each block */
            var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .on("click", function (d) {
                var g = svg.append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

                g.append("rect")
               .attr("width", 200)
              .attr("height", 200)
              .style("fill", "red")
              .transition()
               .duration(750)
              .attr("width", 500)
              .attr("height", 500);
               g.append("text")
               .attr("dx", "200")
               .attr("dy", "200")
                .text(d.info);
                g.append("text")
               .attr("dx", "200")
               .attr("dy", "300")
               .text(d.country);

            });

            /* Create the text for each block */
            elemEnter.append("text")
            .attr("dx", function (d) { return -20 })
            .text(function (d) { return d.label })
        })


data.json file is:
{"nodes":[
  {"x":80, "r":40, "label":"Pam","info":"Developer","country":"India"}, 
  {"x":200, "r":60, "label":"Sam","info":"Programmer","country":"US"}, 
  {"x":380, "r":80, "label":"Ram","info":"Senior Programmer","country":"Canada"}
]}
```

Also how I can bold the written text and put a line below it as a separater.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the event `end`, which would be used like the following:

`d3.select("#myid").transition().style("opacity","0").each("end", myCallback);`

There's a demo of it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692100/invoke-a-callback-at-the-end-of-a-transition)

End is bound to the transition objects, and fires when the transition finishes. `myCallback` would be the function you want to use.

In your case, this would append your text. Since `<b>` tags don't exist for SVG text, you'll want to use the appropriate .css styles for your text. You can either put them in a stylesheet under a `.highlightText` class, or you can apply them with the `d3.select(stuff).css(myCssObject)` method.

Comment: Hello dear, Many thanks yes it worked , also I am having a small query, " Every time I click on Circle svg is formed like below:                                                                  <g transform="translate(250,250)"><rect width="500" height="500" style="fill: none;"></rect><text dx="200" dy="200">Senior Programmer</text><text dx="200" dy="300">Canada</text></g>                                                 So previous text also persists, what I want is to hide the previous text, or create single instance of Label, hide and show it. Can you please help?

Comment: In your transition, try using the `.text()` method on your preexisting SVG text element instead of creating a new text element with `.append`.