# Appending another element when a sibling element's transition ends

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart, which I am using transitions to animate the heights of rect elements like so:

```
//Create a layer for each category of data that exists, as per dataPointLegend values
//e.g. DOM will render <g class="successful"><g>
layers = svg.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(stacked, function(d) {
        return d.dataPointLegend;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.dataPointLegend;
    })
    //transform below is used to shift the entire layer up by one pixel to allow
    //x-axis to appear clearly, otherwise bars inside layer appear over the top.
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,-1)');

//Create a layer for each datapoint object
//DOM will render <g class="successful"><g></g><g>
barLayers = layers.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.dataPointValues;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('g');

//Create rect elements inside each of our data point layers
//DOM will render <g class="successful"><g><rect></rect></g></g>
barLayers
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
        return x(d.pointKey);
    })
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
    .attr('y', height - margin.bottom - margin.top)
    .attr('height', 0)
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
        return i * transitionDelayMs;
    })
    .duration(transitionDurationMs)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + d.pointValue);
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
        return height - margin.bottom - margin.top - y(d.pointValue)
    });
```

I then have a further selection used for appending text elements

```
//Render any point labels if present
//DOM will render <g><g><rect></rect><text></text></g></g>
if (width > miniChartWidth) {
    barLayers
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.pointLabel
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x(d.pointKey) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            var textHeight = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
            //Position the text so it appears below the top edge of the corresponding data bar
            return y(d.y0 + d.pointValue) + textHeight;
        })
        .attr('class', 'data-value')
        .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * transitionDelayMs + transitionDurationMs;
        })
        .duration(transitionDurationMs)
        .attr('fill-opacity', 1);
}
```

This fades in the text elements nicely after all the rects have finished growing in height. What I wondered, was whether its possible to append a text element to the corresponding layer as each bar finishes its transition?

I have seen the answer on this SO - [Show text only after transition is complete d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655719/show-text-only-after-transition-is-complete-d3-js)

Which looks to be along the lines of what I am after, I tried adding an `.each('end',...)` in my rect rendering cycle like so

```
.each('end', function(d){
    barLayers
        .append('text')
        .text(function() {
            return d.pointLabel
        })
        .attr('x', function() {
            return x(d.pointKey) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', function() {
            var textHeight = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
            //Position the text so it appears below the top edge of the corresponding data bar
            return y(d.y0 + d.pointValue) + textHeight;
        })
        .attr('class', 'data-value')
        .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * transitionDelayMs + transitionDurationMs;
        })
        .duration(transitionDurationMs)
        .attr('fill-opacity', 1);

});
```

But I end up with lots of `text` elements for each of my `g` that holds a single `rect` for each of my datapoints.

I feel like I'm close, but need some assistance from you wise people :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
whateverTheSelectionIs    
.each('end', function(d){
        barLayers
            .append('text')
```

`.each` runs separately for every element in your selection, and inside the each you're adding text elements to every barLayer (barLayers). So you're going to get a (barLayers.size() * selection.size()) number of text elements added overall. You need to add only one text element in the each to the right bar / g.

The below is a fudge that might work. It's tricky because the text you want to add is a sibling of the rects in the selection that calls the .each function..., d3.select(this.parentNode) should move you up to the parent of the rect, which would be the right barLayer.

```
whateverTheSelectionIs    
.each('end', function(d,i){
        d3.select(this.parentNode)
            .append('text')
```