# d3 zoom to bounding box II scrolling while zooming throws error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am throwing an error on my implementation of [Mike Bostock's zoom to bounding box II.](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675)

The error stops the zoom mid-way and locks up the map if you scroll during the zooming event.

Any ideas on fixing? The error is present on Bostock's example.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

The code:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 370,
    active = d3.select(null);

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(675)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select(".app-map")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "app-counties-map");

function ready(error, us) {

  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "app-counties")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("click",clicked);

  function clicked(d) {
    if (active.node() === this) return reset();
    active.classed("active", false);
    active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

    var bounds = path.bounds(d),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][3] - bounds[0][4],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][5] + bounds[1][6]) / 2,
      scale = 3.5,
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

    svg.transition()
      .duration(450)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
  };

  function reset() {
    active.classed("active", false);
    active = d3.select(null);

    svg.transition()
      .duration(450)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
  };

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  svg.on("click", stopped, true);

  svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

  function zoomed() {
    g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }

  function stopped() {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }

}


queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "./data/us (2).json")
    .await(ready);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is happening because the mouse wheel event is trying to zoom while the zoom transition animation from click event is still playing ( I didn't get the error in chrome but in IE ).

You could turn the mouse-wheel event off at the beginning of the click event and enable it back on after the animation/transition finish.

In order to wait for the transition to finish, I've used .each, but maybe .call can be used as well.

Added 20150501 8:24PM PST

I am off work now so I can explain in more detail.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewY/Ls85y71t/)

#### 1. Disabling mouse scroll zoom event

```
var _wheelZoomEvent = svg.on("wheel.zoom");
function clicked(d) {

        svg.on("wheel.zoom", null);
```

While click transition is executing, we want to prevent the mouse wheel event from triggering another zoom transition.  svg.on("wheel.zoom") is returning the reference to the event handler, so that I can reattach when the transition is complete. svg.on("wheel.zoom", null) detaches the event handler from mousewheel event.

#### 2. Adding callback at the end of transition

After the transition completes we need to re-attach the mousewheel event back to the svg object.

```
svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event)
            .each("end", function(){ 
                  svg.on("wheel.zoom", _wheelZoomEvent);
            });
```

There is another transition inside reset() function, and we need to attach event back on there as well.

Comment: Here is a linke to SO page how to use callback after transition :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692100/invoke-a-callback-at-the-end-of-a-transition

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I am trying your example (which works well in plnkr -- well done). I am unable in my own implementation to reinstate the zoom behavior. Once the zoom event detaches, it does not reinstate, even with the .each function attaching the _wheelZoomevent obj reference.