# D3 insert conditional at end of transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adapting the following code, that redraws a line at the end of each transition.

```
function tick() {

// push a new data point onto the back
data.push(random());

// redraw the line, and slide it to the left
path
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .each("end", tick);

// pop the old data point off the front
data.shift();

}
```

Source of code: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642874

However, instead of automatically re-calling tick() at the end of every transition, I would like to check whether a certain boolean (myVar) is true, and only in that case re-call tick().

I have tried to write something like this, but the tick() function has stopped being re-called. Can someone please help me understand what's wrong. Thanks.

```
function tick() {

// push a new data point onto the back
data.push(random());

myVar = true //for now just hardcoding the value of myVar

// redraw the line, and slide it to the left
path
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .each("end", function() { if (myVar === true) return tick;});

// pop the old data point off the front
data.shift();

}
```

Note: The new code is adapted from JesperWe's answer here: [Invoke a callback at the end of a transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692100/invoke-a-callback-at-the-end-of-a-transition)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the function you've replaced `tick` with is:

```
function() { if (myVar === true) return tick;}
```

However, D3 doesn't do anything with that return value. Instead you should write it as:

```
function() { if (myVar === true) tick();}
```

so when D3 calls that function, you can conditionally call `tick` yourself within the function you passed.

Comment: The difference is that `tick` refers to the unevaluated function. D3 is calling it automatically when passed as the callback. In the modification, the function that is called returns the unevaluated `tick` function, which won't do anything -- you need to call it explicitly in this case as outlined in the answer.

Comment: Hmm...I've tried doing this suggestion and tick is not being recalled? The exact function now is: function tick() {

    
    data.push(random());

    myVar = true

    
    path
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null)
      .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
        .each("end", function() { if (myVar === true) tick();});

   
    data.shift();

  }

Comment: Check what `myVar` is, then. Maybe the reason why is because it's unexpectedly `false`