# How can I update the D3 sunburst sequence partition to v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to update the d3 sunburst sequence partition to d3 V4, :
the one at: https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

I have switched most of it over and it is mostly working working but it breaks on mouseleave function. The error I get is: *d3.js:7616 Uncaught TypeError: callback.call is not a function*

```
function mouseleave(d) {

d3.select("#trail")
  .style("visibility", "hidden");
d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);


d3.selectAll("path")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .each("end", function() {
          d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
        });

d3.select("#explanation")
  .style("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

Does anyone know if there is something there which does not work in in d3 V4 - I couldn't find it in the docs. Or even better, if any one knows of an updated d3 V4 version of this somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use `on("end", ...)` instead of `.each`. See the documentation here: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on

See also an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537982/343261

An example of slightly different Sunburst (though without on-end): [Zoomable Sunburst on d3.js v4](http://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099)

Comment: Thanks Nixie - can't believe I couldn't find that v4 version! all good now