# Make the Click event unavailable during animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner in d3.js and I am trying to do a collapsible horizontal tree with d3.js. I started with this example :
http://blockbuilder.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

There is one flaw that I try to solve but without success. It is when you click multiple times quickly on the same circle, it launches the same animations many times and it broke the tree.

So I would like to know if there is a possibility to make the click event disabled during the animation and make it available at the end ?
I tried using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773846) to remove the event and put it back, but it does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using timeouts or removing and adding event listeners or tracking transitions, you can check to see if a transition is occurring on any individual node with `d3.active(node)`. It will return either null (in the event of no transition) or the transition if one is taking place. If a transition is occurring, ignore the click event (or more accurately, don't carry out any actions on click events if a transition is happening).

First let's check to see if a selection has transitioning elements:

```
function isTransitioning(selection) {
    var transitioning = false;
    selection.each(function() { if(d3.active(this)) { transitioning = true; } })
    return transitioning;
}
```

Then let's apply that in the click function in your linked example:

```
  function click(d) {
    // Are no transitions happening?
    if(!isTransitioning(d3.selectAll("circle"))) {
        // If none are continue with updating the graph:
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
          } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
          }
        update(d);
    }
  }
```

Giving us:

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
 if(!isTransitioning(d3.selectAll("circle"))) {
  if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
    } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
    }
  update(d);
 }
  }
}



function isTransitioning(selection) {
 var transitioning = false;
 selection.each(function() { if(d3.active(this)) { transitioning = true; } })
 return transitioning;
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

*I had good results with selecting only circles (you can click twice without error and without stopping the transition from the looks of it), but in some cases you might want to select all items with a transition. In this example if selecting all the `g`s you have to wait until all transitions are done before updating again by click:*

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
 if(!isTransitioning(d3.selectAll("g"))) {
  if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
    } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
    }
  update(d);
 }
  }
}



function isTransitioning(selection) {
 var transitioning = false;
 selection.each(function() { if(d3.active(this)) { transitioning = true; } })
 return transitioning;
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe grab the onclik event and throttle the click the duration of the animation in this case 750 milisecs

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to tell if an animation is currently ongoing, and also deal with multiple animations being possible at once. I made a fork here: http://blockbuilder.org/WilliamNHarvey/4a39d034cef90be249b5ab003ecf775d

Make an array that holds current animations
`var animations = []`

Then on click, check if the current node is already animated. If so, cancel the click event. If not, add it to the animations queue. Set a timeout to remove it after 750 milliseconds

```
function click(d) {
  if (isAnimated(d)) return;
  animations.push(d);
  setTimeout(function(){ removeAnimation(d) }, duration);
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

The two functions here, `isAnimated` and `removeAnimation`, simply loop through the nodes to find the one you're looking for

```
function isAnimated(d) {
  res = false;
  animations.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if(e.id == d.id) res = true;
  });
  return res;
}

function removeAnimation(d) {
  animations.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if(e.id == d.id) animations.splice(i, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why loop through the list of animated nodes and check there id? Use a dictionary/object with the id as key.